# Why reference to directive's attribute is broken when object under attribute is changed and ControllerAs is used?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a directive which takes an object as parameter. This object can be changed to another one by parent directive. When I use `$scope`, then object is updated in the directive. When I use `ControllerAs` syntax then reference is broken and change is not reflected. I assumed that in both cases `$scope.obj` and `vm.obj` are references so they should behave in the same way. What is breaking the reference here and why?

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <div>Original object: {{object}}</div>
    <button ng-click="changeObject()">Change object!</button>
    <my-object obj="object"></my-object>
    <my-object-vm obj="object"></my-object-vm>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      var app = angular.module("app", []);

      app.controller("ctrl", function($scope) {
        $scope.object = {
          p1: "A"
        };

        $scope.changeObject = function() {
          $scope.object = {
            p2: "B"
          }
        }
      });

      app.directive("myObject", function() {
        return {
          template: "<div>Obj from scope: {{obj}}</div>",
          scope: {
            obj: "="
          }
        }
      });

      app.directive("myObjectVm", function() {
        return {
          template: "<div>Obj from vm: {{vm.obj}}</div>",
          scope: {
            obj: "="
          },
          controller: function($scope) {
            var vm = this;
            vm.obj = $scope.obj;
          },
          controllerAs: "vm"
        }
      });
    </script>
</body>
```

Plunker:
[working example](https://plnkr.co/edit/3OFw5AEuJgSvsqfSasYd?p=preview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link is broken because you're copying the reference from the scope to the controller only once, when `link()` is invoked. So later, when a new value is assigned to `$scope.obj`, the controller still refers to the old one.

You need to use [bindToColtroller](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-bindtocontroller-) in addition to `controllerAs`:

> When an isolate scope is used for a directive (see above), `bindToController: true` will allow a component to have its properties bound to the controller, rather than to scope.

Comment: Ah, I see now. In my mind I thought that `vm.obj` has reference to `$scope.object` from parent controller (meaning: to whatever `$scope.object` points at). But the case is, the reference is just to specific object and it stays the same. What is better practice: using `$scope` in my directive or using `bindToController`? Or it's a matter of preference?

Comment: Btw. adding `bindToController: true` to the plunker breaks initial values for all divs. But using it in real code worked, thanks.

Comment: It's a metter of preferences and coherence. If your code base uses controllerAs, keep using it. If your code base uses scope, keep using it.